# Intellij IDEA - Web Application - Glassfish - Logging

Tags: java, logging, intellij-idea, glassfish

I wonder if there is a way to see System.out.println Messages in Idea when I´m using Glassfish to handle Websocketconnections. I cant find an Output Window where my messages are displayed. So if this doesnt work: How do you log with this setup ?

Comment: Find out where your Glassfish logs these connections and configure the log file location in IntelliJ IDEA run/debug configuration, Logs tab.

Answer (score 0):

My glassfish log is located in the glassfish window under debug when I run debug. System out messages will show up here in the log messages. You can also find them by navigating to your glassfish log file. My file is located at:

```
C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.txt
```

And here is a pic of that same log in the debug screen. This screen pops up automatically for me when I start the debug server. 
[image]